# problema para instalar 'sf' e 'geobr' no r Ubuntu20.04

Tags: r

Estou tentando instalar o pacote "geobr", mas ele sempre pede para instalar o pacote "sf", que também dá problema na hora de instalar. Uso Ubuntu 20.04.

```
install.packages('geobr')
```

> Installing package into ‘/home/palloma/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘geobr’ is not available for this version of R
>
> A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
> see the ideas at
> https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Erro do sf:

```
install.packages('sf')
```

> Installing package into ‘/home/palloma/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> tentando a URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/sf_1.0-7.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3529597 bytes (3.4 MB)
> ==================================================
> downloaded 3.4 MB
>
> installing *source* package ‘sf’ ...
> ** package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** using staged installation
> configure: CC: gcc
> configure: CXX: g++ -std=gnu++11
> checking for gdal-config... no
> no
> configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
>
> removing ‘/home/palloma/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/sf’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/tmp/Rtmpsl04dl/downloaded_packages’

Comment: Veja se [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49181048/12195738) resposta do site em inglês lhe ajuda para a instalação do `sf`.

Comment: Se o comentário do @Rfroes87 resolver o problema da instalação do pacote `sf`, siga [a resposta do Carlos Eduardo Lagosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/548166/82237) para o pacote `geobr`. Mas verifique as datas to ficheiro do CRAN e do [GitHub](https://github.com/ipeaGIT/geobr) e escolha a mais recente. Só a do GitHub parece estar a ser ativamente desenvolvida.

Comment: Vou apagar essa resposta e colocar uma mais detalhada aqui.

Answer (score 0):

## geobr

Sua primeira mensagem de erro indica que o pacote não está disponível. Se é um que conseguia instalar antes, as causas mais prováveis são:

1. O espelho de repositório está temporariamente fora do ar
2. O pacote foi atualizado e agora exige uma versão mais recente do R
3. O pacote foi removido do CRAN

Para verificar o status do pacote no CRAN, use o link canônico: https://cran.r-project.org/package=geobr. No caso, irá constatar que ele foi removido. Pode baixar e instalar manualmente a partir das versões arquivadas no CRAN ou verificar a página oficial do projeto.

#### Versão arquivada

Usando o link canônico, verifique a última versão arquivada do fonte.

```
link <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/geobr/geobr_1.6.5.tar.gz"
arquivo <- tempfile()
download.file(link, arquivo)
install.packages(arquivo, repos = NULL)
```

#### GitHub (recomendada)

Como o pacote é publicado no GitHub, pode instalar diretamente com `devtools:install_github`. Melhor do que usar as versões arquivadas no CRAN, pois garante que irá instalar a versão mais recente.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ipeaGIT/geobr", subdir = "r-package")
```

Em ambos os casos, como não está fazendo a instalação automaticamente por um repositório, terá que resolver as dependências manualmente.

## sf

O pacote sf, assim como vários outros voltados para dados espaciais, usa [GEOS](https://libgeos.org), [GDAL](https://gdal.org) e [PROJ](https://proj.org). A instalação é independente do R e pode ser feita pelo gerenciador de pacotes da sua distribuição Linux. As ferramentas associadas não são necessárias, apenas as bases, então bastam as bibliotecas de desenvolvimento. Usando APT:

```
apt install libudunits2-dev libgeos-dev libgdal-dev libproj-dev
```

Mas como o próprio *sf* está disponível nos repositórios Debian, é mais simples instalar ele diretamente e deixar o APT resolver as dependências:

```
apt install r-cran-sf
# ou use a ferramenta gráfica de instalação do seu Linux
```

Comment: Por que o voto negativo? A resposta resolve o problema apresentado.